# Defining a certain member function

Tags: c++

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>

struct State { virtual ~State() = default; };

struct Drunk : State {
    void singWhileDrunk() {std::cout << "Singing while drunk.\n";}
};

struct Person {
    State* state;
    void singWhileDrunk() {dynamic_cast<Drunk*>(state)->singWhileDrunk();}  // Is this good?
};


int main() {
    Person bob;
    bob.state = new Drunk;
    bob.singWhileDrunk();
    // dynamic_cast<Drunk*>(bob.state)->singWhileDrunk();  // Using this is better?
}
```

What I wonder is if `Person::singWhileDrunk()` should really be defined in `Person` or not.  `singWhileDrunk()` only has true meaning if the person is drunk, so to define it in `Person` seems wrong to me. However, it does simplify the code in `main()`, especially if it is to be used a lot.

```
(dynamic_cast<Drunk*>(bob.state)->singWhileDrunk();
```

is clearly more typing (and may run into difficulties if I want to redefine it everywhere it is used, e.g. change `dynamic_cast` to `static_cast`).  Another issue I have is that in my program I have many different types of states, each with their own special functions, and to define them all in `Person` will really bloat the `Person` class with MANY, MANY functions that don't even seem to belong in `Person`.  So there seems to be pros and cons to both choices and would like to hear what others have to say about this.

This is just an example of course. In reality, I have states like `FlySpellState`, with the function `flies()`, which also seems to have no place in `Person` (since people cannot fly normally), though it could be.

Comment: Can't a `Person` also sing while `!Drunk`?  Seems to me that the state my alter the result of the function, but it's still the same member function call.

Comment: Well, that's the thing.  There is Person::sing(), which truly belongs in Person, and then there is singWhileDrunk(), which seems to belong in Drunk only. And this is just an example.  In reality, I have states like FlySpellState, with the function flies(), which clearly has no place in Person (since people cannot fly normally).

Comment: But the more I think about it, along with considering Edward's answer, I think I should place these functions in Person.  I just worry about the "pollution" of many such functions in Person.

Answer (score 4):

You should never really be doing any manual casting.
Virtual functions usually provide you with the functionality you are looking for.

How about:

```
struct State
{
    virtual void sing() = 0;
};

struct Drunk: State
{
    virtual void sing() { std::cout << "Singing while drunk.\n"}
}

struct Sober: State
{
    virtual void sing() { std::cout << "Singing Opera.\n"}
}

class Person
{
     std::auto_ptr<State>   state;
     public:
         Person()
            : state(new Sober)
         {}
         void sing()
         {
             state->sing();
         }
         void drink()
         {
             state.reset(new Drunk);
         }
         void sleep()
         {
             state.reset(new Sober);
         }
};
```

Then your code in main is even more trivial:

```
int main() {
    Person   bob;
    bob.drink();  // Don't allow manual changes in state.
                  // Provide actions that internally modify the state of your object.
    bob.sing(); 
    bob.sleep();
    bob.sing();
}
```

> This is just an example of course. In reality, I have states like FlySpellState, with the function flies(), which also seems to have no place in Person (since people cannot fly normally), though it could be.

Sure. So what you want is a bunch of different states. These states can all be changed when diffent situations apply.

```
struct Action
{
    virtual void doAction()  {std::cout << "Nothing Happens\n";}
};

class Person
{

    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Action>>  actionMap;
    Action& getAction(std::string const& action)
    {
        static Action defaultAction;    // Will do Nothing by default.

        auto find = actionMap.find(action);
        return find == actionMap.end()
                  ? defaultAction
                  : *(find->second);
    }

    void sing()
    {
        getAction("sing").doAction();
    }
    void fly()
    {
        getAction("fly").doAction();  // Default do nothing unless you have read the scroll of flying
    }
    void drink()
    {
        actionMap["sing"].reset(new Drunk);
        actionMap["walk"].reset(new Stumble);
        actionMap["talk"].reset(new Slur);
    }
    void readScrollOfFlying()
    {
        actionMap["fly"].reset(new FlySpellState);
    }
};
```

Rather than using `std::unique_ptr` and lots of calls to `new`. You may want to look up the [`flyweight pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

Comment: So bottom line: you also think it is alright to define fly() in Person even though a person normally never flies (even though fly() normally carries out defaultAction.doAction(),i.e. nothing).

Comment: @prestokeys: I don't have enough information to make that call. Maybe you can have a `move(MovementType type)` method. Where `MovementType` is an enum that has `run, walk, swim, fly, ....`

Comment: Yes, you predicted correctly. I do have that function, but for LivingBeing, which is a parent class of Person. Person is also derived from Walk, Run, Climb, Swim, while Bird is derived from LivingBeing, Fly, Walk, Run.

Comment: @prestokeys: Prefer composition over inheritance as a general rule.

Answer (score 1):

To focus on your embedded question, the following code is a problem waiting to happen:

```
dynamic_cast<Drunk*>(state)->singWhileDrunk();
```

When `state` holds a pointer to a type that isn't `Drunk` or a subtype of `Drunk`, the `dynamic_cast` will return a `nullptr`. Thus this code is prone to [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2474018/89999) and should be avoided. There are four main alternatives.

- If, as claimed in a comment, you know with certainty that `state` holds a pointer to `Drunk`, use `static_cast<Drunk*>` to indicate this knowledge and to avoid the overhead associated with a dynamic cast. However this is not substantiated by the code in the question, so I cannot suggest it here.
- As Loki Astari suggests in his answer, redesign the interface to use the dynamic nature of virtual methods. I would typically prefer this approach, as it is more common, and thus less likely to be misread or maintained incorrectly.
- Check the result of the `dynamic_cast`:

  ```
  Drunk* drunk = dynamic_cast<Drunk*>(state);
  if (drunk) drunk->singWhileDrunk();
  ```
- Use the non-pointer form of `dynamic_cast` which throws an exception instead. Make sure that you don't invoke undefined behavior if the original member was `nullptr`, though:

  ```
  if (state) dynamic_cast<Drunk&>(*state)->singWhileDrunk(); // note: may throw std::bad_cast
  ```

As a general comment, however, note that you don't have to make everything a method on `Person`. Sometimes it makes sense to create free functions that accept a `Person&` and extract state information. So assuming it makes sense to either directly access `Person::state` or to add a `Person::getState()`, you could write code like this:

```
void signIfDrunk(Person& person)
{
    Drunk* drunk = dynamic_cast<Drunk*>(person.state);
    if (drunk)
        drunk->singWhileDrunk();
}
```

It's hard to tell here which approach is better, but it's generally accepted that [non-member non-friend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1055576/89999) functions are a better way to compose code.

Comment: No idea why the down-vote. I find your answer legitimate, so +1 to balance that ;)

Comment: But do I really need to check `if (drunk != nullptr)` when I'm certain that singWhileDrunk() is only called when the person is drunk?  For example, singWhileDrunk() is called only after checking ahead of time if the person is drunk or not.

Comment: @prestokeys: If you are certain that your `State*` is a valid `Drunk*` you should use `static_cast<Drunk*>` instead to signal this to the reader (and compiler); `dynamic_cast<Drunk*>` signals that you *don't* know. Of course if it's not inherently obvious why the local code can know this, you may want to comment as well.

Comment: @Michael.  The only reason for dynamic_cast<Drunk*> is because I actually have a vector<State*> of concurrent states for Person (State being the base class), and there is virtual inheritance in State.

Answer (score 0):

You said,

> Another issue I have is that in my program I have many different types of states, each with their own special functions, and to define them all in Person will really bloat the Person class with MANY, MANY functions that don't even seem to belong in Person. So there seems to be pros and cons to both choices and would like to hear what others have to say about this.

If you have to modify `Person` every time a new type of `State` is introduced to your program, it violates the [Open/Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and is a symptom of sub-optimal design.

My suggestion will be to make `State`-specific functions external functions and not member functions of `Person`.

```
void singWhileDrunk(Person const& p)
{
   Drunk* drunk = dynamic_cast<Drunk*>(p.state);
   if ( drunk != nullptr )
   {
      drunk->singWhileDrunk();
   }
}
```

Comment: I also have proxy class PersonProxy derived from Person, that holds a Person* pointer `actual`.  So instead of defining `Person::singWhileDrunk()` and then `PersonProxy::singWhileDrunk() {actual->singWhileDrunk();}` you suggest your solution together with `void singWhileDrunk(PersonProxy& p) {singWhileDrunk(p->getActual());}` ?  In terms of violating the open-closed principle, isn't there equal amount of responsibility in adding the functions either way when new States are added?

Comment: @prestokeys, definitely.